# Draw a chronological timeline with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have data like

```
data = as.data.frame(  rbind(   c("1492", "Columbus sailed the ocean blue"),
                                c("1976", "Americans listened to Styx"),
                                c("2008", "financial meltdown. great.")
                                ))
```

and I want to build a plot in `ggplot2` that will display an arrow for time `aes(x=$V1)` and text for `aes(label=$V2)`. It sounded pretty simple until I tried to draw it.

**update:** I didn't write it but you need to do `as.Date("1492", format="%Y")` to reproduce correctly.

**NB:** Solutions given below only deal with events that occur at a specific date -- not timelines with "periods" or "eras".

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317584/r-ggplot-time-series-with-events

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest graphics are the most difficult to create in ggplot2, but it is possible (and pretty).

```
data =data.frame( V1=c(1492,1976,2008),V2=c("Columbus sailed the ocean blue","Americans listened to Styx","financial meltdown"),disloc=c(-1,1,-.5))
dev.new()
ggplot() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = V1,y = disloc,xend = V1),data=data,yend = 0) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 900,y = 0,xend = 2050,yend = 0),data=data,arrow = arrow(length = unit(x = 0.2,units = 'cm'),type = 'closed')) +
    geom_text(aes(x = V1,y = disloc,label = V2),data=data,hjust = 1.0,vjust = 1.0,parse = FALSE) +
    geom_point(aes(x = V1,y = disloc),data=data) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1492,1976,2008),labels = c("1492","1976","2008")) +
    theme_bw() +
    opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(size = 12.0,angle = 90.0),axis.text.y = theme_blank(),axis.ticks = theme_blank(),axis.title.x = theme_blank(),axis.title.y = theme_blank())
```

[image]

Note: this graphic was produced entirely in the ggplot2 Plot Builder in [Deducer](http://www.deducer.org)

Comment: Ian, the code is perhaps a little messy for those just reading `gg`rammatically. Do you mind if I edit for clarity? Thanks for the great solution.

Answer (score 9):

A little variation of the `ggplot2` version above making use of `geom_lollipop` from `ggalt` and using `cowplot` for the nice background theme. Important to set the figure height as nice and small with a longer width (in my RMarkdown chunk I have `fig.height = 3` and `fig.width = 10`)

I've also used a (slightly adapted) function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071002/moving-x-or-y-axis-together-with-tick-labels-to-the-middle-of-a-single-ggplot-n) which helps move the x-axis (the adapted function uses `annotate` rather than `geom_hline`. This allows me to add an arrow).

Apologies, I have used my own data here for reasons of brevity. I need to get back to work!!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggalt)
library(cowplot)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

#Create data to plot
data <- tribble( ~start_date, ~event, ~displ,
                ymd(20160201), "Initial meeting with Renfrewshire", 1,
                ymd(20160430), "UBDC RAC submission", 0.7,
                ymd(20160524), "College Ethics Approval", 0.5,
                ymd(20160601), "UBDC RAC approval", -0.5,
                ymd(20161101), "Agreeement in Principal", 0.3,
                ymd(20170906), "DSA signed", 0.5,
                ymd(20170921), "Data transferred", -0.5,
                ymd(20180221), "Analysis complete", 0.5)


#Function to shift x-axis to 0 adapted from link shown above

shift_axis <- function(p, xmin, xmax, y=0){
      g <- ggplotGrob(p)
      dummy <- data.frame(y=y)
      ax <- g[["grobs"]][g$layout$name == "axis-b"][[1]]
      p + annotation_custom(grid::grobTree(ax, vp = grid::viewport(y=1, height=sum(ax$height))), 
                            ymax=y, ymin=y) +
        annotate("segment", y = 0, yend = 0, x = xmin, xend = xmax, 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "inches"))) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
              axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

    }


#Conditionally set whether text will be above or below the point
vjust = ifelse(data$displ > 0, -1, 1.5)

#plot
p1 <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(start_date, displ)) +
  geom_lollipop(point.size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = start_date, y = displ, label = event), data = data,
            hjust = 0, vjust = vjust, size = 2.5) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8)) +
  expand_limits(x = c(ymd(20151201), ymd(20180501)), y = 1.2) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 9))

#and run the function from above
timeline <- shift_axis(p1, ymd(20151201), ymd(20180501))
```

Produces....

[image: Timeline for one of my thesis projects]

Answer (score 7):

This looks kind of OK...
[image]

```
dislocations <- c(-1,1,-.5)
ggplot( data )
+ geom_text( aes(x = V1, y=dislocations, label = V2), position="jitter" )
+ geom_hline( yintercept=0, size=1, scale="date" )
+ geom_segment(  aes(x = V1, y=dislocations, xend=V1, yend=0, alpha=.7 ))
```

but it still lacks a proper "time arrow", the background doesn't look right, and it labels values on the `y` axis.

Comment: I think that looks pretty decent myself.  background and arrows are simple enough to deal with.  good job

Comment: @isomorphismes Is it possible to get the x-axis values on the horizontal line using ggplot2 like the image in the question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695311/chronological-timeline-with-points-in-time-and-format-date)

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a better job for R's base graphics (really, this kind of thing probably better fits with a tool like Illustrator or something of that ilk).

```
dat = as.data.frame(rbind(c("1492", "Columbus sailed the ocean blue"),
                       c("1976", "Americans listened to Styx"),
                       c("2008", "Financial meltdown")))
dat$V1 <- as.Date(dat$V1,"%Y")
dat$val <- c(-1,1,-0.5)

plot(dat$V1,dislocations, type = "n",xaxt = "n",bty = "n", 
     xlab = "Time", ylab = "Dislocations")
u <- par("usr")
arrows(u[1], 0, u[2], 0, xpd = TRUE)
points(dat$V1,dat$val,pch = 20)
segments(dat$V1,c(0,0,0),dat$V1,dat$val)
text(x=dat$V1,y=dat$val,labels=dat$V2,pos=c(4,2,2))
```

produces something like this:

[image]

Comment: Does Illustrator let you use Data? I thought you just drew things in it.

Comment: @LaoTzu That was mostly an offhand comment, sorry. I just meant that the graphic you describe feels more like something one would design by hand than a "data graphic". You certainly could do this in Illustrator, but you're right, you most likely would have to measure out the axis distances yourself.